# Connection reset by peer error TensorFlow

Tags: git, docker, tensorflow, ioerror

I am trying to build an image recognizer program using TensorFlow and Docker I keep getting the following error when I try to train a classifier,
using this code:

```
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files/flower_photos
```

as such: [image]

```
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

and then when I ran the code again I got the error:

```
IOError: CRC check failed 0x76f1f85e != 0x6caceac0L
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Try using host network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working on the issue, I figured out that there was an error with unzipping the inception v3 file and so I had to manually install the directory off of the TensorFlow git and put it into the tf_files directory and then delete in the file image_retraining.py the DATA_URL that contained the link for the inception v3 file as well as the method that used the DATA_URL.

Answer (score 0):

@Research 2: While running the code, folder named inception must be getting created in your tf_files folder.
1) Delete that folder 
2) Download the file from "http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz"
3) Unzip it and place it in tf_files

Now open the file retrain.py and comment the whole method def maybe_download_and_extract() or this method is getting called from another method def main(_), it is the 7th line in this method, comment that out and try running your code again, it would work perfectly fine.

@Aritroper: Thank you for the answer

Comment: I dont know why it was down voted, it is the right solution, if you cant get it to work, doesn't mean the answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem TODAY when trying to install tensorflow==2.12.0.
Force updated urllib3 to 2.0.4 and I worked fine!

```
pip install -U urllib3
```